# Is it possible to update filter rules in Thunderbird via custom extension?

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon, thunderbird-webextensions

Hi and thank you for your attention.

I want to create an extension for Mozilla Thunderbird that implement some sort of black list.
It is possible to create filter rules for mails and I want to add a button which create filter rule for selected mail. These rules are stored in msgFilterRules.dat file and I could manually edit it but only when Thunderbird is closed.

Is there any way to manipulate this file with some sort of API or WebExtensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to John Bieling from https://thunderbird.topicbox.com/groups/addons

> currently we have no API to manipulate filters, but it has been requested and we will add that eventually. In the meantime, you could implement your own filter system, by listening for new messages and move them if they hit your own blocklist:
> https://webextension-api.thunderbird.net/en/91/messages.html#onnewmailreceived
> https://webextension-api.thunderbird.net/en/91/messages.html#move-messageids-destination